# Storing java.sql.Timestamp type into HSQL database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, casting, hsqldb

We do have multiple databases for our application.

The date of type java.sql.Timestamp is being stored in DATETIME data type of SQL SERVER.

But

For storing same type in HSQL DB, I am using TIMESTAMP, and it is not able to cast it.

I will not be able to change in java code because it is working in SQL Server and Oracle both, but I need casting in hsql query only.

Current working query with SQL Server with datetime field is:

```
insert into SYSTEM_DOCUMENTS values(?)
```

Java code:

```
timeStamp=new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
String q="insert into SYSTEM_DOCUMENTS values(?)";
pstm = con.prepareStatement(q);
pstm.setTimestamp(1, timeStamp);
pstm.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Show us your Java code

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Added my java code.

Comment: executeQuery() should **not** be used for DML statements. Use `executeUpdate()` instead (this is clearly documented in the JavaDocs)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Hibernate` it can be simple by adding `@Temporal` annotation

```
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date date;
```

`Temporal` has `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE`, `TIME` enums

Comment: Not using hibernate..and I dont want to chage java code, instead I want to implement it in HSQLDB query.